# range-v3: Joining piped ranges with a delimeter

Tags: c++, range-v3

I'm trying to build a basic demo of the range-v3 library: take some integers, filter out odd values, stringify them, then join those into a comma-separated list. For example, `{ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 }` becomes `"8, 6, 0"`. From reading the [docs](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html) and going through examples, it seems like the naïve solution would resemble:

```cpp
string demo(const vector<int>& v)
{
    return v |
        ranges::view::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }) |
        ranges::view::transform([](int i) { return to_string(i); }) |
        ranges::view::join(", ");
}
```

but building on Clang 7 fails with a static assertion that one, "Cannot get a view of a temporary container". Since I'm collecting the result into a string, I can use the eager version - `action::join` - instead:

```cpp
string demo(const vector<int>& v)
{
    return v |
        ranges::view::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }) |
        ranges::view::transform([](int i) { return to_string(i); }) |
        ranges::action::join;
}
```

but the eager version doesn't seem to have an overload that takes a delimiter.

Interestingly, the original assertion goes away if you collect `join`'s inputs into a container first. The following compiles and runs fine:

```cpp
string demo(const vector<int>& v)
{
    vector<string> strings = v |
        ranges::view::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }) |
        ranges::view::transform([](int i) { return to_string(i); });
    return strings | ranges::view::join(", ");
}
```

but this totally defeats the principle of lazy evaluation that drives so much of the library.

Why is the first example failing? If it's not feasible, can `action::join` be given a delimiter?

Comment: At first glance this question resembles https://stackoverflow.com/q/48383671, but there seems to be different problems at play there. `ranges::to_<string>` doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Why don't you return auto instead of string? This will allow you to make it truly lazy

Comment: You certainly would outside a demo like this, but that just makes the static assertion occur elsewhere. Eventually you want to collect the result into a string (for I/O or storage in another structure), and it fires there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`action::join` should accept a delimiter. Feel free to file a feature request. The actions need a lot of love.

Comment: Where do we file a feature request?

Answer (score 1):

Some changes since the original question have resolved this.

- The original problem of views on a temporary container has been patched in the ranges-v3 library. [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36820639/how-do-i-write-a-range-pipeline-that-uses-temporary-containers) [Commit](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/commit/d800a032132512a54c291ce55a2a43e0460591c7#diff-717d5566d9b53787ef3ff55ab11059b5c63bffc7a1a5c797908654d8d4b084a2)
- Aside: The namespaces have been renamed to `ranges::views` and `ranges::actions`

I've updated your two examples:

#### "Lazy" version

But your demo above doesn't compile because `ranges::views::join()` returns a view over the individual characters of the joined strings. You can use the ranges-v3 `to()` utility to join to a string

```cpp
string demo1(const vector<int>& v)
{
    return v |
        ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }) | // filtered view over int
        ranges::views::transform([](int i) { return to_string(i); }) | // view over strings
        ranges::views::join(", ") |  //  view over chars
        ranges::to<string>; // flattened to a string
}
```

#### "Eager" version

The eager version works but `actions::join` still doesn't accept a delimiter. You can add one using `ranges::view::intersperse(", ")`.

```cpp
string demo2(const vector<int>& v)
{
    return v |
        ranges::views::filter([](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }) |
        ranges::views::transform([](int i) { return to_string(i);}) |
        ranges::views::intersperse(", ") |  // view over strings 
        ranges::actions::join; // joined to a string
}
```