# C++ Copying std::strings from STL container to another STL string

Tags: c++, c++20

### An ugly block of code that we would like to get rid of

I have this block of code in one of my source files - yuck!

```
std::string error;
std::vector<string> errors;
// ... populate errors with some strings
for(const auto &item : errors)
{
    if(!error.empty())
    {
        error += std::string("\n");
    }
    error += item;
}
```

I think there should be a better way to do it, possibly taking inspiration from `ostream_iterator`. See [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/)

### An initial attempt, which on reflection isn't an improvement

My first thought was that perhaps `std::for_each` would work with a lambda.

```
std::for_each(errors.cbegin(), errors.cend(),
    [&error] (const auto &item)
    {
        if(!error.empty())
        {
            error += std::string("\n");
        }
        error += item;
    }
);
```

But then I realized that this is really no improvement what so ever, and in some ways obfuscates the code further through the unnecessary use of a lamba where the range based for loop worked perfectly fine, and was clear to understand.

### A similar working example with `ostream_iterator`

I think that there should be a way to take inspiration from `std::copy` or `std::for_each` to do this.

The example given using `cout` and `ostream_iterator` is the following:

```
std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it(std::cout, ", ");
std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), out_it);
```

It is pretty close to what I want to achieve. Instead of `std::cout` it should use an instance of a `std::string` object. Instead of `", "` the delimiter should be `"\n"`. It already iterates over a vector, and calls `out_it`, the argument of which should be a `string` instead of `int`.

But I don't think this will quite work, since a `string` does not inherit from `ostream`. It is not an `ostream` type.

### A final failed attempt

I also attempted this, but didn't really expect it to work. (It doesn't compile.)

```
std::for_each(errors.cbegin(), errors.cend(),
    std::back_inserter(error)
);
```

What to do?

Comment: Or the C++20-era equivalent [Joining a range of strings with a delimiter using standard ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63637187/364696).

Comment: Remark about the title: some things in the C++ standard library are based on (taken from?) the STL library, but from a standard C++ point of view, STL isn't really a thing anymore, so std::string might be clearer and 'container' in the context of C++ should be clear enough.

Comment: Also, you're actually asking for an elegant join function with separators only in between items. This isn't obvious from the title.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah, I see it can be done with a `stringstream`. Not quite what I had in mind, but if it works I guess it looks like it could be a good option

Comment: `std::string` has never been a part of the STL.

Comment: @Evg Not sure about that - string is in std, templated containers which I assume is what you mean by STL are in std. Should be fairly clear what is meant

Comment: No, they're just being pedantic. The STL *was* a thing. It no longer is. From it, we now have the C++ Standard Library. However, enough people use both terms interchangeably that it *should* be understood what's meant unless someone is working with ancient code/tooling.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Your idea with `std::ostream_iterator` can be easily improved to make working [code like this](https://godbolt.org/z/6efajzGen), is it beautiful enough, the way you wanted? It has no loops.

Comment: @Arty It looks decent, however my query would be is there any overhead with using stringstream? For my purposes, it doesn't actually matter but I would be interested to know the performance numbers

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant My solution above was only meant to make it look more different then a loop solution. If most important for you is speed (and memory consumption), not beuty, then you need other strategy and make [this kind of code](https://godbolt.org/z/PKcrdEx7h). This code has two advantages, first that it at start pre-allocates resulting `error` string of exactly size that is needed, this allows to consume less memory and do fewer heap allocations (`error += errors[i];` may re-allocate Heap many times, and final size of string might be bigger than necessary).

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Continuing previous comment. Second advantage of my mentioned code is that it uses `std::memcpy()`, that is fastest possible way of copying memory, because regular operation like `error += errors[i];` besides doing heap re-allocation also may copy in a loop char by char, with constructing char object (although I expect modern C++ stdlib does optimization of using `std::memcpy()` too). Anyway my code that I mentioned does everything by hand in low-level fasion, so should have highest speed and smallest memory consumption. Although my low-level code looks longer then yours.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant One more very considerable speedup can be made if size of delimiter (character `'\n'` in your case) is known to be exactly 1 character. Then in my last mentioned code above it is advantageous to replace adding delimiter to `error` not by `std::memcpy()` as I did (inside `if (i > 0) { ... }` block), but through much faster and simpler code `if (i > 0) { error[off] = delim[0]; ++off; }`. And also better to make type of `delim` not `std::string` but `char` type in this case. This only works if delimiter is known to be just 1 character.

Answer (score 3):

Benefiting from the adoption of [`views::join_with`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2441r2.html#implementation-experience) and [`range::to`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1206r7.pdf), in C++23 you can simply do

```
std::vector<string> errors;
auto error = errors | std::views::join_with('\n') 
                    | std::ranges::to<std::string>();
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aKKWofa6r) (with range-v3 equivalent since [no compiler implements them yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp23))

Comment: That said, the OP specifically tagged C++20, so this won't do any good without taking a dependency on `range-v3`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this bitwise or operator being applied to vectors of strings... Am I misinterpreting something here?

Comment: I see this appears to be related to ranges, which isn't something I am familiar with. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

In which case, should this not be supported by C++ 20 compilers?

Comment: `views::join_with` comes from C++23, so you need to wait for a C++23 compiler.

Comment: Can't accept as an answer until we're C++ 23 compliant, but gladly give an upvote

Comment: OP wanted to filter by not-empty, which ranges can do too: `views::filter([](auto& s) { return !s.empty(); })`

Comment: @Ben There is no need to use `views::filter`, `views::join_with` already handles this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is too much you can do with this except wrap it in a function so the rest of your code is a little tidier. I went for this version:

```
std::string smush(std::vector<std::string> const& errors)
{
    std::string error;

    for(auto const& e: errors)
            error += e + '\n';
    error.pop_back();

    return error;
}
```

Comment: He only wants to append (and prepend a `\n` on entries that are non-empty. This is not the same output, is it?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Nope, it seems you overlooked the question ^^ The emptiness check is only for the first iteration where `error` is empty (and thus useless to perform every time, since it is not empty after the first insertion). The goal was to prevent to start with a delimiter. The output of the proposed solution here is the same, but without the unnecessary branching.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I think you'll find his code appends all entries regardless if they are empty or not. His test for emptiness is made to ensure his resultant string doesn't have a `"\n"` at the beginning.

Comment: I reversed which variable was doing what in my head.  Indeed what you both say is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-ugly piece of templated code that I use whenever I need to join strings together (I have it in a utilities header), along with an optional end piece too.  Will work with any collection type that supports `std::begin` and `std::end` (fixed-size arrays as well, though if you have a pointer and length, you'll have to wrap it in a `std::span` first), and as long as the *element* inside supports the `<<` operator to make a string with, should work with custom types too.

```
// Joins collections of strings together.
template<typename InputCollection>
std::string joiner(const InputCollection& collection, const std::string& separator = ", ", const std::string& ending = "")
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    auto begin = std::begin(collection);
    auto end = std::end(collection);

    if (begin != end)
    {
        os << *begin++;
    }

    while (begin != end)
    {
        os << separator;
        os << *begin++;
    }

    os << ending;
    return os.str();
}
```

So it's wordy, but it's easy-to-understand, which I consider more important.  Use like this:

```
vector<string> collection = { "hey", "there", "all" };
auto output = joiner(collection); // output: "hey, there, all"
std::string stringArray[3] = { "now", "an", "array" };
output = joiner(stringArray, "-"); // Different separator - output: "now-an-array"
```

So use that if you think it'll be beneficial long-term, but that's obviously longer than what you had originally.